# DbFit - Cannot work out how to run in Standalone Mode

Tags: dbfit

OK, I'm still a newbie to DBFit. I have downloaded the files from here: [Dbfit download page](https://github.com/dbfit/dbfit/releases/download/v2.1.1/dbfit-complete-2.1.1.zip)

and run startFitnesse.bat

The following in Flow Mode works perfectly:

```
!path lib/*.jar

!|dbfit.SqlServerTest|
!|Connect|jdbc:sqlserver://10.19.135.119;databaseName=DbFit_Temp;user=dbfittemp;password=dbfittemp|

!|insert|MyTable|
|field1 |
|yyy|

!|Query| select * from MyTable|
|field1|
|yyy|
```

So when I try the following to test Standalone Mode according to [this link](http://gojko.net/FitNesse/book/ch12.html#N1213E):

```
!path lib/*.jar

!|import| 
|dbfit.fixture| 

!|DatabaseEnvironment|sqlserver|
!|Connect|jdbc:sqlserver://10.19.135.119;databaseName=DbFit_Temp;user=dbfittemp;password=dbfittemp|

!|insert|MyTable|
|field1 |
|yyy|

!|Query| select * from MyTable|
|field1|
|yyy|
```

I get the following error:
"Could not find fixture: import."

I've googled around and can't find a complete example to show me how to run DbFit in Standalone Mode....please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked out the problem after I saw this [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dbfit/standalone/dbfit/m20af5jFyho/wgyjRJn7V6kJ)

The syntax for the Import should be:

```
!|import fixture| 
|dbfit.fixture|
```

The documentation I've seen doesn't seem to show that however...