# Dbfit cannot find fixtures

Tags: fitnesse, dbfit

I wrote the folowing test but am getting error:

**Could not find fixture: Connect.**

> !path lib/*.jar
>
> !|Import| 
>   !|dbfit.SqlServerTest|
>
> !|Import| 
>   |dbfit.fixture|
>
> !|Connect|Data Source=ACER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NopCommerce;Integrated Security=SSPI;|
>
> !|query|select * from dbo.Employees|
>
> !|Query| select 'test' as x| |x| |test|

[image: here is the errors]

Answer (score 1):

Include the following at the top of your page:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}
```

Comment: Why? What does this do

Comment: There are two test systems that can run in FitNesse, fit and slim.  DbFit only runs under the 'fit' test system.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21150221/3734141), the syntax for the import should be:

```
!|import fixture|
|dbfit.fixture|
```

Note: the **dbfit.fixture** is in a separated row, and has no preceding exclamation mark, the sign of a command, so the mentioned error message should be read as: "Oh, I have found **import** command asking for something like **dbfit.fixture**, but the next line asks for a **Connect** fixture, which is not expected, because **Connect** is [another command](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/reference.html#connect)".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
|import fixture|
|dbfit.fixture|

!|DatabaseEnvironment|sqlserver|
|Connect|192.168.0.3|user|pass|nz_db|

|Store query|!-select * from sql_tbl-!|fromtbl|

!|Query|<<fromsql|

|Rollback|

!|dbfit.util.ExportFixture|
|dbfit.fixture|
```

This works for me in DBFit Java.

Answer (score 0):

Anything (even comments) between the 'DatabaseEnvironment' and the 'Connect' will also cause the 'Could not find fixture: Connect' error.

So, this fails:

```
|DatabaseEnvironment|sybase|

|Connect | jdbc:jtds:sybase://10.158.0.189:8000;user=myuser;password=mypass;databaseName=mydb |
```

But this works:

```
|DatabaseEnvironment|sybase                                                                                                 |
|Connect             |jdbc:jtds:sybase://10.158.0.141:8000;user=myuser;password=mypass;databaseName=mydb|
```